# Consuming a WCF Service with Monotouch via SSL (https) + basicHttpBinding

Tags: iphone, wcf, ssl, https, xamarin.ios

I'm currently writing a iphone app which will consume WCF services over a secure connection (SSL/https). I have managed to consume this service while testing locally via http.

Now we want to make sure the service is secure, so we've set up a UAT server with a properly signed certificate to run our tests.

We are using a custom binding, coupled with security mode `TransportWithMessageCredentials` which requires a username/password in the `ClientCredentials` property.

Generated the proxy using `SISvcUtil.exe`

When I try to call this secure service from the iPhone, I get a rather lovely generic error of:

`Exception in async operation: System.Net.WebException: There was an error on processing web request: Status code 500(internal server error)`
([Here is a pastebin of full exception](http://pastebin.com/nV2BwL77) ).

I've tried implicitly accepting the certificate using:
`ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallBack = (sender, cert, chain, ssl) => true;`
but this just returns the same 500 error.

The same code works great on a windows machine but not on the iphone. Has anyone else come across this problem and/or know of a solution to it?

Comment: Have you enabled WCF tracing on the server to see what could be going on inside of the WCf pipeline? This will help you to diagnose any errors that are due to the transport, rather than application-level code.

Comment: I'm stuck with the same problem. I genereted the proxy with SLSVCUTIL.EXE. I'm also working with a self signed certificate.

I would like to know if you have found an alternative solution?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - We are using a similar method to the way you've done it. Generated the proxy using SLSVCUTIL, then created our own custom binding (based on `BasicHTTPBinding`). We do all of our communication via HTTPS (we ended up buying an appropriate certificate because the phone had trouble with a self signed cert). Sorry I can't be more of a help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it would seem that at the time of writing, Monotouch doesn't support WCF very well (it currently has a barebones implementation).

Due to this, and the need for decent security around our webservice, we've decided to go down a different route; validating the user via username+password over a secure, encrypted SSL connection everytime the web service is called. We use Silverlight 3.0 `SiSUtil.exe` to generate the bindings for the webservice rather than include it as a web reference in the project.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a bug in monotouch, it may not have full implementation of generated proxy using SISvcUtil.exe, did you try generating a mac app and test it on mac?

Does monotouch have any documented example with support on WCF proxy? If they dont have then probably it may not work, monotouch does not provide a .NET runtime, instead it actually compiles everything to native ios binary. So if WCF proxy is not correctly transformed, it will not work.

Comment: http://wiki.monotouch.net/HowTo/WebServices/Using_WCF here is a wiki entry with regards to generating proxy's to use within Monotouch - and I've also had this proxy working for http; so I'm inclined to say that this isn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Generally when getting Internal Server errors I've found the cause to be a problem with the HTTP headers being sent in the request.  I don't really use WCF on MonoTouch so I'm not sure about the implementation.